# Static files loading in production but not development

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static-files

Usually I have this issue exactly the other way around!

In my development environment my Django app will not load some of my static files, specifically ones that I have added myself: that is, the two packages I've added to my app (`admin` and `ckeditor`) are both loading up fine, but two of the folders I've created and linked myself (`img` and `css`) are not being found. Here's a map of my directory:

```
root
 |-- blog    (this is the name of my app)
 |-- mysite  (name of my site)
      |-- settings.py
      |-- urls.py
 |-- media
 |-- static
      |-- admin
      |-- ckeditor
      |-- css
      |-- img
```

As stated, `ckeditor` and `admin` load fine while the others do not. Here's an example from the `runserver` output in debug mode (the file at `static/css/base.css` exists in my file tree):

```
GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 200 690627
GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
GET /static/admin/css/widgets.css HTTP/1.1" 200 10340
GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1761
GET /static/img/brand.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1764
```

Here's some other information which may be of interest:

- It works fine in production! I assumed this was because I had dedicated aliases in my apache config, but that doesn't explain why `admin` and `ckeditor` work.
- I have routed media in much the same way (see the settings file below) and that works fine in development.
- I am using the template tag `{% load static %}` as instructed by the Django docs. In older versions I used `{% load staticfiles %}` and I've tried that too.
- I have run `collectstatic` in both environments.
- Running with `DEBUG=False` works fine in production (all the static files load) but no static files load at all when `DEBUG=False` in development. This is to be expected though, since in development I don't have a web server to handle this (to clarify, I *usually* run the server in debug mode, but have tried turning this setting off and on to see what changes occur)

In an effort to help anyone debug my problem, here are some relevant excerpts files:

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: @nik_m yes, in both environments - I'll add that to the question

Comment: in your urls.py the ckeditor path does not have a `/` try giving it and see.

Comment: The static files for `ckeditor` are already being loaded fine in both environments. Adding the `/` seems to have no effect, on either the `ckeditor`'s static files or on the static files which are not being loaded.

Comment: ok, then one more suggestion for the static_root and media_root,`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')` and `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')` try this.

Comment: As above, this has no obvious effect - in fact, the requests made to the server are identical to ones made before the change.

Comment: What is the location of your settings file?

Comment: @2ps `settings.py` is in the folder `mysite`. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your apps list, Django actually does NOT load files from STATIC_ROOT when DEBUG is True.

When DEBUG is enabled Django uses STATICFILES_FINDERS option that by default is:

```
[
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

FileSystemFinder will find files stored in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting 
and AppDirectoriesFinder is looking for files in a `static` subdirectory of each app.

That's why folders admin and ckeditor work - Django doesn't use your /root/static folder at all when DEBUG is True. Instead it gets files by AppDirectoriesFinder from apps `static` subdirectories.
Something like .../3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django-ckeditor/static/...

When you run `collectstatic` command it collects all static files that STATICFILES_FINDERS can find and copies them into your STATIC_ROOT (/root/static/) and if DEBUG is False Django just uses this folder instead of STATICFILES_FINDERS

So how you can make it work with debug enabled. Just create a folder and add it to STATICFILES_DIRS like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'some_new_static_folder'),
]
```

Also you can delete all files from `/root/static/` you don't need to create anything inside this folder manually, `collectstatic` will do it automatically for production.

Answer (score 7):

This is an easy approach for handling static files in django (that works out of the box if you use Django default options):

1. **Don't ever put anything yourself into the folder you specify as `STATIC_ROOT`**.
2. Put static files specific to an app into the folder `static` inside the app.
3. For static files that do not directly belong to an app, create the folder `static_files` within your project and add to your settings: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),]`. *Obviously you can choose another name, `static_files` is just a suggestion.*
4. **For production** run `collectstatic` so that Django collects your static files (from points 2. and 3.) and puts them into the folder you created in 1.

If you are in debugging mode you are done after step 3.

---

**In your case**, the problem was that you put static content into the `STATIC_ROOT` which is a folder Django wont look for content in debugging mode.
`admin` and `ckeditor` work because they follow step 2., thus their static files actually come from the folder of the installed app and not from your `static` folder when in debugging mode.

---

So, **here is how to fix your issue**:

- do step 3. from above.
- move your folders `img` and `css` to the folder created in step 3.
- (optional) wipe your `STATIC_ROOT` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your urlpatterns are correct, which means the issue is most likely that `settings.DEBUG = False` in the settings file.  Make sure `settings.DEBUG` is `True`, and the static files should load.  You can verify this by either using `manage.py shell` and checking the value of the `DEBUG` flag.

The only other issues to look for is whether you are pointing to the correct urls file in your settings by verifying the `ROOT_URLCONF` setting and whether your `BASE_DIR` points to the parent directory of the `static` directory.  Both values can also be verified in `shell`.

For example, if your settings file is located in `/path/to/root/blog/settings.py`, then you set `BASE_DIR` as :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Forgive me for not being clear: although I talk about `settings.DEBUG` being `False` in the additional information, it is usually set to `True` in development. In the case mentioned above, I tried changing it to `False` to see what effect it would have, and the behaviour was essentially as expected. I'll be sure to clarify this in the question. To confirm, I have checked the `manage.py shell` and also forced a 404 error while running the server: both indicated `DEBUG=True`. Further, my `BASE_DIR` exactly the same as you suggest - I'll make sure the question reflects this too.

Answer (score 1):

I also had some issues with local files and this help my situation.

I do store my static files on S3 but you can adjust your image location URL.

```
if DEBUG == False:
    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = "//%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = "//%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
else:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```