# CSS not loading on django on different settings environments

Tags: css, django

I'm using Django as a framework, and I want to hide a column on mobile view with CSS.

I use three different settings files: base, dev, and prod.
All the main settings are in the base file and the only difference between the dev and prod settings - in what database I'm using (local Postgres and remote Postgres on Railway).

I have my base.html file, where I load static files:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/base.css' %}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'main/img/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

That's my project structure:

[image]

I want to hide a column on mobile view, so that's what I have in my base.css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td:nth-child(1) {
    display:none;
  }
  th:nth-child(1) {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

However, when I run the app using dev settings - everything works fine. When I run using prod - changes are not displayed.
It seems that CSS file is not being read, but I'm wondering why if the code is the same - the difference is only in using different databases on different settings.
I already did `collectstatic` with changes in CSS and pushed it to the server.
But even when I run the app with prod settings locally - still the CSS is not taking into consideration.

This is how I manage static files in my base settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'static'
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static files loading in production but not development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972837/static-files-loading-in-production-but-not-development)

Comment: When you open css file url manually do you see unmodified file or error message?

Comment: Maybe the issue is that when I checked staticfiles -> static -> main -> CSS -> base.css - I see that there are no new changes. 

I run collectstatic with both dev and prod environments.

@IvanStarostin

Comment: Show your settings for all envs related to static files.

Comment: have you used :    {% load staticfiles %} in html file

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you are not getting css after run collectstatic in production.

Why you are not getting because you have not added `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py file.

**Serving static files in production:**

`STATIC_ROOT`: This is the absolute path to a directory where Django's collectstatic tool will gather any static files referenced in our templates.

Try adding `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py file and run `collectstatic`.

STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS these three must be there inside settings file for production use.

**settings.py file:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

This should work perfect now in production.

Comment: Unfortunately the same result

Comment: what error you got

Comment: No error - just it doesn't load the CSS

Comment: Maybe the issue is that when I checked staticfiles -> static -> main -> CSS -> base.css - I see that there are no new changes. I run collectstatic with both dev and prod environments.

Comment: No, didn't work with updated answer. Should I wipe out the existing staticfiles, and make collectstatic again?

Comment: do collectstatic again

Comment: please share settings.py file

Comment: should I do collectstatic on dev or prod environment? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: You need to do it in production only

Comment: I did collectstatic with both dev and prod settings - and the problem didn't disappear. Should I wipe out the current content of staticfiles, and do collectstatic again? I'm wondering what settings should I use to do collectstatic properly.

Comment: Manoj - I updated my questions - I added how I handle static files in my base settings. I have STATIC_ROOT there.

Comment: Also, I have added staticfiles, and then made collectstatic with prod settings. The same result.

Comment: instead of this: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  try only this: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: And your staticfiles dir is not correct. try this: STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
)

Comment: You were did mistakes in settings file while adding static root and staticfiles dirs

Comment: No, the new solution doesn't work: https://monosnap.com/file/IDsCMSq0yFOxqXpvoU2mjYUBiOw4GM

Comment: You got this error because of incorrect staticfiles dirs

Comment: Your staticfiles dirs and my staticfiles dirs are different checkout my answer

Comment: In staticfiles dirs, you are closing parenthesis after base_dir, you need to close this after static

Comment: I got it. Changed accordingly, doesn't work: https://monosnap.com/file/etyhDMD3qbi3nRV22m5lBneWKsLv84

Comment: I did it this way: https://monosnap.com/file/8D91CAq4GYrtlbOEF7z4YriXtnbjXm
Now it works on prod, but doesn't work on dev :)

Comment: Defining STATICFILES_DIRS is not a must. Setting it equal to STATIC_ROOT makes no sense, the option is misused. And list of STATICFILES_DIRS has to be surrounded with square brackets, not parenthesis. Renaming folders back and forth I'm afraid is a misleading advice also. Collectstatic cannot work differently with the same settings. Looks like OP is missing something in his setup.

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi ok i got this error, do one thing, move that static folder inside an app. after this, in  STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/appname/static/') ).. According to your error i did this. and your STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'). and make sure your staticfiles_dirs begin with parenthesis not square brackets according to my answer. And now this will work in prod and dev too

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving my static folder where I have my images and CSS to the app folder.
Then I put these settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And deleted STATICFILES_DIRS - it is not necessary.

Now it works both on prod and dev.
Thank you, @ManojTolagekar and @Ivan Starostin.